# setTimeout makes the text unidentified

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I want to write a code that accepts my string and display it after 4 seconds

I wrote this code to show hi after 4 seconds but instea,d it shows the string right away and after 4 seconds
it becomes unidentified. My code is here:

```
`setTimeout(myMessage, 4000);
function myMessage(message){
const para = document.querySelector('.text');
return para.innerHTML = message;
}
myMessage('hi');`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `undefined` value is happening because you are setting `myMessage` as the callback for your `setTimeout` function without passing it a `message` argument. The `setTimeout` callback does not except any arguments, so when you pass a function in like this:

```js
setTimeout(myFn, 1000);
```

It's the same as doing this:

```js
setTimeout(() => myFn(undefined), 1000);
```

To fix this, you can change your setTimeout implementation like so:

```js
setTimeout(() => myMessage('another message'), 4000);
```

Hope this helps!